# How to make other people see the VFX?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local VfxFolder = RS:WaitForChild("VfxFolder")
local DashClone = VfxFolder:WaitForChild("DashClone")
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Char = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

local Hum = Char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local HRP = Char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")

local WKeyDown = false
local AKeyDown = false
local SKeyDown = false
local DKeyDown = false

local DashDeb = false
local DashTime = 0.3

local AnimationFolder = script:WaitForChild("AnimationFolder")

local ForwardDashAnime = Hum:LoadAnimation(AnimationFolder:WaitForChild("ForwardDash"))
local BackDashAnime =  Hum:LoadAnimation(AnimationFolder:WaitForChild("BackDash"))
local LeftDashAnime = Hum:LoadAnimation(AnimationFolder:WaitForChild("LeftDash"))
local RightDashAnime =  Hum:LoadAnimation(AnimationFolder:WaitForChild("RightDash"))

local Event = script:WaitForChild("Event")

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Key,IsTyping)
    if IsTyping then return end
    if Key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Q then
        if DashDeb == false and Char:FindFirstChild("Deb") == nil then
            DashDeb = true
            delay(DashTime + 0.7,function()
                DashDeb = false
            end)
            if WKeyDown then
                coroutine.wrap(function()
                    DashEffect()
                end)()
                local Tween = TweenService:Create(HRP,TweenInfo.new(DashTime,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out),{Velocity = HRP.CFrame.LookVector * 70})
                Tween:Play()
                ForwardDashAnime:Play()
                Event:FireServer("Dash")
                delay(DashTime + 0.1,function()
                    ForwardDashAnime:Stop()
                end)
            elseif AKeyDown then
                coroutine.wrap(function()
                    DashEffect()
                end)()
                local Tween = TweenService:Create(HRP,TweenInfo.new(DashTime,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out),{Velocity = HRP.CFrame.RightVector * -70})
                Tween:Play()
                LeftDashAnime:Play()
                Event:FireServer("Dash")
                delay(DashTime + 0.1,function()
                    LeftDashAnime:Stop()
                end)
            elseif SKeyDown then
                coroutine.wrap(function()
                    DashEffect()
                end)()
                local Tween = TweenService:Create(HRP,TweenInfo.new(DashTime,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out),{Velocity = HRP.CFrame.LookVector * -70})
                Tween:Play()
                BackDashAnime:Play()
                Event:FireServer("Dash")
                delay(DashTime + 0.1,function()
                    BackDashAnime:Stop()
                end)
            elseif DKeyDown then
        coroutine.wrap(function()
                    DashEffect()
                end)()
                local Tween = TweenService:Create(HRP,TweenInfo.new(DashTime,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out),{Velocity = HRP.CFrame.RightVector * 70})
                Tween:Play()
                RightDashAnime:Play()
                Event:FireServer("Dash")
                delay(DashTime + 0.1,function()
                    RightDashAnime:Stop()
                end)
            end
        end
    end
end)

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if UIS:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.W) then
        WKeyDown = true
    else 
        WKeyDown = false
    end
    if UIS:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.A) then
        AKeyDown = true
    else 
        AKeyDown = false
    end
    if UIS:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.S) then
        SKeyDown = true
    else 
        SKeyDown = false
    end
    if UIS:IsKeyDown(Enum.KeyCode.D) then
        DKeyDown = true
    else 
        DKeyDown = false
    end
end)

function DashEffect()
    for i = 1,7 do
        local Clone = DashClone:Clone()
        Clone:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(HRP.CFrame)
        Clone.Parent = workspace
        game.Debris:AddItem(Clone,0.5)
        spawn(function()
            for i,v in pairs(Clone:GetChildren()) do
                spawn(function()
                    if v:IsA("MeshPart") or v:IsA("Part") then
                        v.CFrame = Char:FindFirstChild(v.Name).CFrame
                        for i = 0.25,1,0.1 do
                            v.Transparency = i
                            v.Reflectance = i
                            wait()
                        end
                        Clone:Destroy()
                    end
                end)
            end 
        end)
        wait(0.05)
    end
end
```

This script but in the last function [DashEffect] will only be seen by one person. What should I do to make others see the VFX?
i tried create this VFX in server script but its kinda delay and not smooth like in Local script

I just need to make others see the VFX without delay and get smooth like local script